# Filtrar resultados por id do usuário logado

Tags: laravel

Estou construindo um sistema usando o framework Laravel (tenho pouco conhecimento no fw) e estou preciso pegar o id do usuário que logou para fazer as consultas baseadas no id do usuário.

Ex: UsuarioUm => lista todos os produtos cadastrado com o id do usuário.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você também pode usar a relação HasMany no model usuario, considerando que tem na tabela produtos a key do usuario (usuario_id)

```
class Usuario extends Eloquent{
  public function produtos(){
    return $this->HasMany('Produto');
  } 
}

class Produto extends Eloquent{
    public function usuario(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Usuario')
    }
}
```

e na consulta você pode fazer:

```
if(Auth::check()){ //se tem usuario logado
    $usuario_produtos = Auth()->user()->produtos();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$userID = Auth::user()->id;
```

ou

```
$id = Auth::id();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users

Exemplo:

```
$products = Product::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
```

ou se você tiver o relacionamento entre user e products, simplesmente:

```
$products = Auth::user()->products();
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o Auth para pegar o usuário que logou no sistema:

```
if (Auth::check()){ //verifica se tem usuario logado
    $usuario_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $usuario_produtos  =  Produto::where('usuario_id', $usuario_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

com Laravel poder pegar o usuario com importe da biblioteca.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
```

exemplo de codigo

```
$file = DB::table('nomdatabela')
                    ->where('name', 'like',  "%" . $_nome)
                    ->where(function($query){
                        $Users = Auth::tabelausuarios()->nome;                        
                        return $query->where('nome', 'like',  "%" . $Users)
                        ->pluck('name');                        
                            }                        
                        )
                    ->get();
```